# how to get the facebook like button to be specific based on variables passed to the page

Tags: php, html

i am working on a website that is big into php databases i'm trying to get it so there is a (facebook)like button for every post that is made for the site. the only problem is the facebook likes are not individualized and are page specific so when i like 1 they all get liked. this would not be a problem if i could put each one in the comment section of the post since it is on a different page but each comment section is individualized by a php id variable that i pass to it (which does not actually change the url but only what shows up on the page). is there any way that i could make it so that each like button behaves on its own?
here is the site i have been working on.

www.linkerbolt.com

Comment: You want each of these like buttons to "like" a separate page? Because a Facebook user cannot like a certain page more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the div that you've created which contains the facebook like button, you can add a data-href property, and in this property you can add a link to whichever page you want :

```
data-href="www.whicheverpageyouwant.com"
```

In your case, you would need a different URL for each post. You can create a page that receives a post id and displays a single post (www.yoursite/posts/35) and set the data-href to point to each corresponding page when you have to display several on the same page.

**Ficticious example :**

```
<?php foreach ($forumPosts as $post) : ?>

    <div class="fb-like" 
        data-href="wwww.yoursite/forumpost/<?php echo $post['id'];?>" 
        data-send="true" 
        data-width="450" 
        data-show-faces="true" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: yes but will the page change dependent on what my id variable is

Comment: for example if i pass in blabla.php?id=1 will that be a page from blabla.php?id=2

Comment: Those would be two different pages.